# End all processes but windows standard

Tags: c#

I have this script that end all processes but it also terminate windows default processes which cause a blue screen

How can I terminate all processes without this to happen

```
Process self = Process.GetCurrentProcess() ;
foreach( Process p in Process.GetProcesses().Where( p => p.Id != self.Id ) )
{
  p.Kill() ;
}
```

Comment: Check the `Process.ProcessName` property in your loop and check for windows default processes, so basically you could make a white-list of process names which you don't want to kill and check if the process name is in that list and if so, don't call `.Kill`, (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.processname?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Here is a link to a page which lists common windows process names (https://www.pcsecurityworld.com/132/list-of-common-processes-under-windows-task-manager.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to have whitelist of process names which is not going to be killed.
check my example below.

```
Process self = Process.GetCurrentProcess() ;

IList<string> whiteList = new List<string>() {"svchost.exe", "explorer.exe"....};
foreach( Process p in Process.GetProcesses().Where( p => p.Id != self.Id &&  !whitelist.Contains(p.ProcessName ) )
{
  p.Kill() ;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest if the user already knows standard list of applications to be closed, then it is better to maintain it as a list - thoughts ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari it depends I suppose, on which list would hold more items, in any case, another way to improve on this would be to either store the white-list as a database table and just pull the values from their and convert to a `List<T>` or place the values in the `.config` or `appsettings.json`, that way you don't have to change the code base in the application.

Comment: @RyanWilson - yeah agreed.